# Sub accounts in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create a website where a user logs in and adds one or more children (sub accounts, but they are not user accounts).

The user can then create an entry for each child, like a journal entry.  I want the user to be able to select the child on a top level, then submit the journal entry without having to re-select which child this entry is for.  The user will select one of the children the user created and everything the user does in this "sub account" — like upload photos, submit journal entries, or whatever — is done for the selected child. I want to avoid a scenario where the user is adding a new journal entry and if the user created more than one child, the user has to select which child this entry is for every time.

I've looked at the Ajax Tab control and the Multiview control but I'm not sure if this will work, because then I would need to create a new tab/view dynamically every time the user adds another child. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not going to find what you want in a single control. You'll have to design how the interface will work and build it from a number of different controls to get it to do what you want.

Comment: On the back end, I recall doing something like this and handled it through the built-in ASP.Net Profile system - added user "relatives" where "relatives" aren't "users" (not part of ASP.Net membership). Just an idea...hth..

Comment: Thanks for answers, I figure maybe nested master pages will work.